# Xmldocument equivalent in XDocument

Tags: xml, xpath, c#-3.0, xmldocument, linq-to-xml

I wrote the following code using XMLDocument

```
string Query = @"/ShortcutList/" + Modality;
            XmlNodeList nodes = shortcutsXMLDocument.SelectNodes(Query);
            if (nodes == null)
            {
                // if the modality not exists, I will load the Default one 

                Query = @"/ShortcutList/Default";
                nodes = shortcutsXMLDocument.SelectNodes(Query);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < nodes[0].ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            {
// do something here
}
```

where `shortcutsXMLDocument` is XMLDocument

How to convert it using xDocument , I failed to find the equivalent to SelectNodes in xdocument

any idea please

Answer (score 1):

Well the code is rather odd as SelectNodes always returns an XmlNodeList so the check `if (nodes == null)` will never be true and you can just as well remove it.
As for the first two lines, you could replace them with

```
List<XElement> nodes = shortcutsXMLDocument.Elements("ShortcutList").Elements(Modality).ToList();
```

assuming that the `Modality` variable contains simply an element name and not a complete XPath expression.

Then for the `for` loop you could use e.g.

```
foreach (XNode node in nodes[0].Nodes()) {
  // do something here with node
}
```

but I suspect that we could write clearer and simpler code if you tell us what you want to achieve by posting a sample of the XML and some explanation of which data you want to extract.